# How do I resolve "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error?

Tags: python, arrays, string, indexing

```
def closest(s, queries):
    for query in queries:
        c = s[query]
        for i in s[query:]:
            if s[i] == c:
                return i
            else:
                return -1
```

In the code above, I have a string `s` = "abcaccba" (say) and I have an array of indices, queries = `[1, 3, 2]`. I am trying to find the closest occurrence of the character at these indices.

For example: `s[1] = b` and the closest index at which the second occurrence of b is, is at 6. When I try to run the code above, I get this error:

```
File "solution.py", line 23, in closest
    if s[i] == c:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Your `i` is a character from the string `s`, not an integer.

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(s[query:])):`

Comment: @Varun, when I try that it gives me another error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want the function to do. What is thd expected output corresponding to those args?

Comment: @PM2Ring, in the example above: I want the outputs 6, 3 and 4 as the indices of the closest occurences of the characters b, a and c at indices 1, 3 and 2

Comment: That info belongs in the question itself. Don't hide it down here in the comments. But how come the output for 'a' is 3, not 0 (or 7)? You don't accept the same position as the output for 'b' or 'c'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `find()` string method to look up character positions in a string.

Look at the string segments ahead and behind of each `query`-indexed character.  Then use their relative position to determine their true index in `s`.

```
s = "abcaccbaz"
queries = [1, 3, 2, 0, 5, 6, 8]
closest = []

for q in queries:
    char = s[q]
    pre = s[:q][::-1] # reversed, so nearest character to char is first
    post = s[q+1:]

    pre_dist = pre.find(char) 
    pre_found = pre_dist >= 0

    post_dist = post.find(char) 
    post_found = post_dist >= 0

    if post_found and (post_dist <= pre_dist or not pre_found):
        closest.append(post_dist + len(pre) + 1)
    elif pre_found and (pre_dist <= post_dist or not post_found):
        closest.append(q - pre_dist - 1)
    else:
        closest.append(None)

closest
# [6, 0, 4, 3, 4, 1, None]
```

I added an additional edge case, `z`, to cover the case where there are no additional instances of that character.  In that case, the procedure returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`i` already a character in string. You just need to change `s[i]` to `i` and calculate the position of character.

```
def closest(s, queries):
    for query in queries:
        c = s[query]
        for i in s[query:]:
            if i == c: # i is a char , i = s[position]
                print( i,(s[query+1:].index(i)+query+1) )
                break
            else:
                pass

s = "abcaccba"
queries = [1, 3, 2]
closest(s, queries)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because `i` is a `string` but indexes must be `integers`. (This should be clear from the error message). Changing the piece `if s[i] ==c:` to `if i == c:` would make your code run but I do not think it will give you the answer you are really looking for.

Since you want the closest index in which the character is the same as that of the index of the query, I think you should get as a list of results which should be as long as the `len`gth of your `queries`. Below is some code that can help you achieve that goal. I have also extended your example to enhance understanding.

```
s = "abcaccba" 
queries = [1,3,2,0, 5]
def closest(s, queries):
    print('String: ', s)
    print('Query: ', queries)
    results = []
    for query in queries:
        c = s[query]
        if s[query] in s[query+1 :]:
            results.append(('query = {}'.format(query), 'character = {}'.format(c), 'index of next occurrence = {}'.format(1+query+s[query+1 :].index(c))))
            #results.append((query, c, 1+query+s[query+1 :].index(c)))
        else:
            results.append(('query = {}'.format(query), 'character = {}'.format(c), 'index of next occurrence = {}'.format(-1)))
            #results.append((query, c, -1))
    return results
closest(s  = s, queries =  queries)
```

Here is the output

```
String:  'abcaccba'
Query:  [1, 3, 2, 0, 5]

[('query = 1', 'character = b', 'index of next occurrence = 6'),
 ('query = 3', 'character = a', 'index of next occurrence = 7'),
 ('query = 2', 'character = c', 'index of next occurrence = 4'),
 ('query = 0', 'character = a', 'index of next occurrence = 3'),
 ('query = 5', 'character = c', 'index of next occurrence = -1')]
```

Comment: Sorry @Rabbid76, I had mistakenly pressed the post answer button. I have posted my answer now.